# CSS gradient button

Tags: html, css

I have made a gradient button based on pure css.

But for some reason it looks different in firefox and chrome.

I want the way it looks in FF that is the gradient starting from left top....but in Chrome it takes from top to bottom.

```
<div id="foo2_pag" class="pagination" style="display: block;">  <a id="second" href="#"><span>London</span></a> 
</div>
```

JsFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/rY94J/1/

Can you please take a look.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't contain any element with class .pagination. This is better http://jsfiddle.net/rY94J/5/ . Also you should mention how do you want it to look

Comment: Try the code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rY94J/7/

Comment: Guys sorry forgot to put the class pagination(didn't expect the down vote :p)....

Comment: Itay if you see the button in both browsers then it looks different.In Chrome it takes the effect from top to bottom whereas in FF it is from left to center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were using `left top`, but Mozilla browsers require a slightly different code, as shown in [linear-gradient - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/rY94J/8/)

```
background:-webkit-gradient( linear,
                             left top, left bottom,
                             color-stop(0.05, #BED630), color-stop(1, #0DB04B) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( to bottom, #BED630 5%, #0DB04B 100% );
```

- P.S - This answer is based on your fiddle's code, but you may want to add some extra settings so it will be cross-browser. Using the standard `linear-gradient` (`-moz` prefix is redundant on new FF browsers) is one improvement you can make.

---

## linear-gradient Syntax

```
Formal grammar: linear-gradient(  
   [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+ )
   \---------------------------------/ \----------------------------/
     Definition of the gradient line         List of color stops  

        where <side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]
           and <color-stop>     = <color> [ <percentage> | <length> ]?
```

Comment: Thanks Itay.I got it worked by changing the position. background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom , right top, color-stop(0.05, #BED630), color-stop(1, #0DB04B) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( to right, #BED630 5%, #0DB04B 100% );Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah in one browser it was from top to bottom and on one from left to right so I had to guess which option are you trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a standard linear-gradient style of:

```
background:linear-gradient( 180deg, #BED630, #0DB04B );
```

Answer (score 1):

use this for cross browser gradient

```
/* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eab730), to(#db5500));
/* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #eab730, #db5500);
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#eab730, endColorstr=#db5500);
/* For Internet Explorer 8 */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#eab730, endColorstr=#db5500)";
```

[updated jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/rY94J/10/)

Comment: Thanks Sonasish for your help.Actually what I want is to start the gradient from left to center and not from top to center.Just looking at Itay's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend the gradient editor on [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Create your gradient in a nice WYSIWYG editor and it will auto-generate cross-browser compatible code, including SVG fallbacks for IE9 if you want it to. Indispensible tool IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working cross browser example of gradient rounded button that might help someone:

[css & html on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/XMK9oPHosg)

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">Big beautifull gradient button</h1>
    <button type="button" class="gradient btn-lg bigrounded btn-block blue xxl">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.gradient {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   margin: 0 2px;
   outline: none;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: .5em 2em .55em;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
   -webkit-border-radius: .5em; 
   -moz-border-radius: .5em;
   border-radius: .5em;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
.bigrounded {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
}
.blue {
  color: #d9eef7;
  border: solid 1px #0076a3;
  background: #0095cd;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00adee', endColorstr='#0078a5');
}
.blue:hover {
  background: #007ead;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0095cc', endColorstr='#00678e');
}
.blue:active {
  color: #80bed6;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0078a5), to(#00adee));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0078a5,  #00adee);
  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0078a5', endColorstr='#00adee');
}
.xxl{
  font-size:50px;
  padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation for the code? It would make better answer.

Comment: You r welcome to ask any particular line of code you are interested, beside that most of the basic css code is self explanatory and the rest is to make it working cross browser.