# CSS:put two colors in the same button

Tags: css

[image]

How can I put two colors in the same button like the one in the picture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS gradient button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590153/css-gradient-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put two colors in the button by using:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #8930fd, #49ccf9);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use gradient colors.

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a button from a linear gradient having 2 positions like this:

```css
.invite {
    background: #823efc;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#823efc), color-stop(100%,#4cc1f9));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #823efc 0%,#4cc1f9 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%,#4cc1f9 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #9c9e9f 0%,#4cc1f9 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #823efc 0%,#4cc1f9 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#823efc', endColorstr='#4cc1f9',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<button class="invite">invite</button>
```